# Spring batch: Writing column names as first line in flat file

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I want to create a flat file which has the below format:

```
Col1Name;Col2Name;Col3Name
one;23;20120912
two;28;20120712
```

As seen, the first line in the flat file are the column names.

How to achieve this through header callback ?

I see that if the input file is of above format, there is an option as below to ignore first line:

```
<property name="firstLineIsHeader" value="true"/>
```

Also, this [Jira Issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-211) indicates that what I want is implemeted and closed. However, I am unable to find any example for writing first line as column names.

```
<beans:bean id="MyFileItemWriter" class="com.nik.MyFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="delegate">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
            <beans:property name="resource" value="file:MYFILE.dat" /> 

            <beans:property name="lineAggregator">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                    <beans:property name="delimiter" value=";" />
                    <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
                        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                            <beans:property name="names" value="Col1Name, Col2Name, Col3Name" />
                        </beans:bean>
                    </beans:property>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="headerCallback" ref="MyFileItemWriter" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

My Item Writer looks as below:

```
public class MyFileItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyBean>, FlatFileHeaderCallback, ItemStream{

private FlatFileItemWriter<MyBean> delegate;    

 public void setDelegate(final FlatFileItemWriter<MyBean> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {


}

public void write(List<? extends MyBean> items) throws Exception {
    this.delegate.write(items);

}

public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
     this.delegate.close();

}

public void open(ExecutionContext arg0) throws ItemStreamException {
     this.delegate.open(arg0);

}

public void update(ExecutionContext arg0) throws ItemStreamException {
     this.delegate.update(arg0);        
}

}
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well did you try to work with

```
  public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
      //... e.g. writer.write("my first line");

  }
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But I thought that would be synonymous to hard coding. Instead, I thought there would be a way present to list down the header directly from bean property names automatically. So want to confirm that there is no such functionality available. If not, I will go with the above way.

Comment: to minimize the hard coding you could re-use the attribute name list with e.g. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-list

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it. Could you please check out the new question posted by me - Footer Call Back getting called after AfterStep call...

Answer (score 18):

create a custom class which extends the FlatFileItemWriter and implements just the constructor:

```
public class MyFlatFileWriter extends FlatFileItemWriter {

    public MyFlatFileWriter (){
        super.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {

            public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                writer.write("Col1Name,Col2Name,Col3Name");

            }
        });
    }
```

and then use this class in the bean configuration class attribute

Answer (score 2):

FlatFileItemWriter gives you option to add a header callback

> headerCallback will be called before writing the first item to file.

So you need to Implement your Header Callback by implementing [FlatFileHeaderCallback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileHeaderCallback.html)

Or [Use Default Implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/sample/support/HeaderCopyCallback.html)